# How to get a Bootstrap 5 container to fit to height of screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 and trying to display a calendar on a screen; however the height is about 25% longer than the screen height. How do I get the container height to fit to the screen height. I have also tried "height: 100%" and "height: 80%" in the css.

css

```
.sectionHeight {
    height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="calendarAdmin"  class="container sectionHeight" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('images/body-bg.jpg');">

    <div id="includedContent"></div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 beta">
        <h3>Full Callendar</h3>
        
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <span id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse1" style="color: red; background-color: white;"></span>
        </div>
        
        <div id="loader"><img src="images/spinner.gif"/></div><!-- loading spinner -->
        
        <div class="whiteBackground" id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you place css rule for html and body have 100% of height?

Comment: @AloisoGomes - Yes as stated I have tried "height: 100%".

Comment: Try remove class "container", it have bootstrap rules marked as !important, or just try add "h-100" to class

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/sizing/

Answer (score 4):

You can use bootstrap utilities to set the width and height relative to the viewport.

```
<div class="min-vw-100">Min-width 100vw</div>
<div class="min-vh-100">Min-height 100vh</div>
<div class="vw-100">Width 100vw</div>
<div class="vh-100">Height 100vh</div>
```

To make it fit your needs:

```
vh-100
vh-75 
vh-50 
vh-25
```

[Relative to the viewport](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the universal selector *
go in your css and delete the margin and padding default of bootstrap. tray to set

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box !important;
  margin:0 !important;
  padding:0 !important;
}
```

set everything as important to override the bootstrap default settings

Comment: Hi Dawid, thank you; however, no joy.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to keep the browser window from scrolling I would use CSS's [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property to force the calendar to scroll in its parent **IF** this is absolutely necessary.

If the full calendar must display in the screen I would adjust font sizes, margins, and padding at breakpoints.

Comment: The purpose is to have the full calendar displayed on the screen as it changes size.

Comment: Is there appointment info in the calendar or simply a month view?

Comment: I thought using row-cols might be straightforward, but the integer cannot be 7 because it does not fit into the grid.

Comment: There is appointment information in the calendar.